# Odd html quirk in chrome I cant figure out

Tags: html, google-chrome

I have my website here: http://8wayrun.com/

This is how a news block looks in Firefox; this is how its supposed to work and how it used to look in Chrome as well.

[image]

However, recently it started looking different in chrome, and I can't figure out how to fix it. Please help!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this in your css:

```
a.button { vertical-align: top; }
```

The problem section was the Continue reading...

Comment: Hmm... that does seem to fix it. Why is this necessary though? This is clearly a bug in Chrome right?

Comment: I can't say it's a bug. Every browser has it's way of rendering a page. (if you wanted this effect than the bug would have been in firefox instead) Since the element was set to display: inlile-block; it's usualy good practice to set its vertical-align to the needs in advance.